# How to query the most recent n records from Azure Table Storage?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am using the following query in c# .net:

`TableQuery<MyType> query = new TableQuery<MyType>().Take(50);`

This works in grabbing 50 records, but I want to grab the most recent (descending) records from the table. I have looked at other answers, but none were concise or working.

**What is the most efficient way to grab *n* most recent records from an Azure Table Storage entity? Please provide a concise answer with a working code example.**

Edit: I'm particularly interested in how Azure Storage Explorer navigates 'cached items'. I can easily order my results (amongst millions of rows) within Azure Storage Explorer by clicking on the column. This will return me what I want, however, I'm not seeing any documentation on how to access these 'cached items'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to fetch latest records from Azure Table Storage as it does not allow you to sort the records on attributes. Records in Azure Table Storage are always sorted by `PartitionKey` and then by `RowKey` within a partition.

One way to fix this problem is to specify the `PartitionKey` value as reverse chronological ticks (something like `(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d20")`) so that whenever you add an entity, it will be prepended (i.e. added to the top of the table). Now when you do the query and fetch "x" number of records, you will always the most recent records.

Other option is to fetch all entities and do the sorting on the client side. This is highly inefficient and is generally not recommended. This solution might work if you have very small number of entities (less than 1000 for example) in your table.

Comment: I have read this answer before, but it does not answer my question because it will not work for data that is already in the table.

Comment: In Azure Storage Explorer, I can order by a column we have called 'Timestamp'. This table has millions of rows, but it orders by 'Timestamp' in under a second. There must be a way to replicate this in code?

Comment: Azure Storage Explorer does the sorting on the data which is fetched (1000 entities max).

Comment: How does it grab and sort these so quickly? How would i replicate in code?

Comment: Is there any concern that this approach can possibly generate tick-based row keys which are not unique, producing collisions?

Comment: You should never use time as the partition key / row key unless you can guarantee that the values are unique (which is much harder than it sounds in a distributed system).

Comment: @xxbbcc - In table storage, combination of partition key and row key has to be unique (and that identifies an entity in a table). You can have same row key value for entities having different partition keys.

Comment: @GauravMantri Sure, that's true as long there are parts of the key that make it unique. Pretty much all implementations with time that I've seen eventually ran into collisions because whoever designed it didn't consider the possibility of the same time being used in parallel requests.